# Use of undeclared type 'SpringView' Github project MengTo/Spring - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

This could be the silliest question, but I am trying to use the MengTo/Spring iOS Animation in Swift (link to Github [Spring](https://github.com/MengTo/Spring) ). But for some reason not able to get it working. I am getting error: use of undeclared type 'SpringView'

I followed the steps below:

1. Dragged the "Spring" folder inside my project in Xcode.
2. Created a UIView and connected it to SpringView class
3. Set the attributes mentioned
4. Created an outlet named "layer" in the view controller

As soon as I create the outlet, I get an error 'Use of undeclared type 'SpringView''

I am not sure what else is there in this. Can anyone help?
Thank you.
Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you also need to use

```
import Spring
```

if you use cocoapods to add spring in your project.

Answer (score 3):

you probably added Spring as a folder reference and not created a new group.
The files inside the folder reference will not be compiled, so it does not work.

Just delete the folder from XCode and drag the Spring folder in, but this time check "Create groups" during adding.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
import Spring
```

To the top of your file where you are using Spring